# How to account for imprecision of measurement used in clinical trial statistical testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clinical-trials, precision

Suppose an assessment used in a clinical trial is imprecise, i.e. given the same patient, two physician conclude different scores (but without bias). Also let's assume the level of imprecision is known, as determined by the variation when N number of doctors assess the same patient.

Now consider a multi-site randomized clinical trial with two arms, where X number of doctors will be evaluating Y number of patients. In this scenario, is there a need to account for the imprecision introduced by having the different doctors? If so, how is this imprecision accounted for in clinical trial statistical testing, e.g. t-test between the randomized groups?

Any literature on this would be helpful.

Comment: If the doctors ratings are correlated (within doctor) this will introduce non-independence, which should be taken into account in the analysis.  In the situation you describe, I would fit a 3 level multilevel model (patients level 1, doctor level 2, site level 3).

Comment: Is the measure used in the randomization scheme? Does the measure, on average, stratify patients?

Comment: @Todd , the measure is not used in the randomization scheme and does not not stratify patients. It simply arises when the doctors determine patient scores because the assessment relies on semi-qualitiative clinical judgement.

Comment: @JJReagh is it the main outcome of the study?

Comment: @Todd , Yes, the primary endpoint.

Comment: Is this a real scenario or a hypothetical? Few people would go through the trouble of multi site randomization without an events committee designed to reduce the variability of a subjective endpoint.

Comment: This is in fact a real scenario. A reduction in the variability of the assessment was considered, however only to the extent of ensuring all doctors "passed" a case study assessment. However a "pass" was considered anything above 75% correct, with respect to the "ideal" assessment, i.e. the assessment of a key opinion leader. Passing scores ranged from 75% to >95%, with an estimated standard deviation of 10%. This variability is not being accounted for in statistical testing. I would imagine there should be a way to account for the imprecision in the assessment.

Comment: You might consider treating the true, unknown outcome state as a continuous [latent variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable), of which the assessment represents a noisy, discretized 'measurement'. Working within a Bayesian framework, such models are rather straightforward to construct. It sounds as if you might even have some nontrivial amount of knowledge regarding differences in skill between your assessors. If so, then you may wish to manifest this knowlege in your models as well.